# How to integrate ELCImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, ios4, alassetslibrary

I am using ELCImagePickerController in my app. According to the demo downloaded from Github the code I have used is

```
ELCAlbumPickerController *albumController = [[ELCAlbumPickerController alloc]    initWithNibName:@"ELCAlbumPickerController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];    

ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initWithRootViewController:albumController];

[albumController setParent:elcPicker];

[elcPicker setDelegate:self];

ELCImagePickerDemoAppDelegate *app = (ELCImagePickerDemoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[app.viewController presentModalViewController:elcPicker animated:YES];

[elcPicker release];
[albumController release];
```

Now it is not going to work as ELCImagePickerDemoAppDelegate is not the AppDelegate of my application.So what should be the correct code to integrate this image picker to my app.
I also tried adding a UIViewController subclass to my app and calling

```
[self presentModalViewController:elcPicker animated:YES];
```

But that does not show the picker and logs a message

```
deallocing ELCImagePickerController
```

Can anyone guide me to right direction ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just do as follow

in .h file add this

```
#import "ELCImagePickerController.h"
```

and conforms to `ELCImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol

and in .m file add this at top

```
#import "ELCImagePickerController.h"
#import "ELCAlbumPickerController.h"
```

and add following code where you want to show the picker

```
ELCAlbumPickerController *albumController = [[ELCAlbumPickerController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ELCAlbumPickerController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];    
    ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initWithRootViewController:albumController];
    [albumController setParent:elcPicker];
    [elcPicker setDelegate:self];
    [self presentModalViewController:elcPicker animated:YES];
```

and also include the required protocol methods

Comment: `- (void)launchController {
 
    ELCAlbumPickerController *albumController = [[ELCAlbumPickerController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ELCAlbumPickerController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];    
    
    ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initWithRootViewController:albumController];
    
    [albumController setParent:elcPicker];
    
    [elcPicker setDelegate:self];
   
   [self presentModalViewController:elcPicker animated:YES];
}`

Comment: I am using above code and calling launchController from a different function.But this does not help either

Comment: the above code is perfectly works for me but not for you means there is some implementation problem with you just follow all steps properly

Comment: Just to clarify, in your project you have added all the ELCImagePicker related files and then in a separate UIViewController subclass added code as mentioned above,right?

Comment: Using the code opens the ELCAlbumPickerController in modal view but it always shows Loading... on the nav bar and albums are not populated.I found that `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{.. }` is not executing in `viewDidLoad` of `ELCAlbumPickerController`.Any idea why?My iOS deployment target is `iOS 5.0` and using `LLVM GCC 4.2` compiler.

Comment: the only difference is the compiler i use default Apple LLVM compiler 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Try not using initWithNibName...

```
#import "ELCImagePickerController.h"
#import "ELCAlbumPickerController.h"

ELCAlbumPickerController *albumController = [[ELCAlbumPickerController alloc] init];
    ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initWithRootViewController:albumController];
[albumController setParent:elcPicker];
    [elcPicker setDelegate:self];
    [self presentModalViewController:elcPicker animated:YES];
```